# AIC of a weighted cox regression model (coxphw)

Tags: survival, cox-model, aic, weighted-regression

I have to compare three cox-regression models.
However, one of these violates the PH assumption. Stratfying the variable did not work because it is already categorical. Thus, weighted cox regression would be suitable.
I was wondering wether one can extract AIC of a `coxphw`model from the package `coxphw`?
Using `extractAIC(model3)`just gave `5`.
Also, is it even possible to compare the models because they employ different methods?

## Update:

I found [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10980-011-9595-1) article by Smith, Betts, Forbes et al. (2011). They mention [this article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1207/s15327906mbr3103_5) by Chou and Bentler (1996) and write

> Because of the weighting, the weighted Cox hazards model is not a true likelihood approach; therefore, we used the Wald χ2 statistic as a large sample approximation to the likelihood, and used −χ2 + 2 * (number of parameters) of the model, as an approximation of AIC (Chou and Bentler 1996).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's wise to compare standard Cox models with `coxphw`-weighted models via AIC. With AIC comparisons among models you need to watch out for possible offsets of reported AIC values by a constant. See the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#Software_unreliability). Although I haven't thought this through carefully, I fear that the estimated likelihood implied in the work-around proposed by Smith et al might not be comparable to the partial likelihood from a standard Cox model, particularly with respect to that constant offset. You could examine that issue with models of simulated data, I suppose.

For comparing models with different predictors on the same data set, it's probably best to stick with the same model-fitting approach: all standard Cox or all `coxphw`. If proportional hazards hold for one Cox model then the `coxphw` weighting shouldn't matter, as the event-average (standard Cox) and weighted-average (`coxphw`) models should be pretty much the same. If PH doesn't hold for a Cox model it won't for the `coxphw`-weighted model either. You just get what might be considered a better "average HR" estimate--of something that, absent PH, isn't really an HR.